# Controller not defined in a Typescript application after upgrading to 1.3

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have the following code in my application:

```
angular.module('home', [])
    .controller('homeHomeController', HomeHomeController)
    .controller('homeContentController', HomeContentController);
```

and

```
class HomeHomeController {
    static $inject = [
        '$http',
        'examService',
        'stateService',
        'userService'
    ];
    constructor(
        private $http: ng.IHttpService,
        private $es: IExamService,
        private $ss: IStateService,
        private $us: IUserService
        ) {
        var self = this;   
    }
}
```

I just upgraded to AngularJS 1.3 and now I am getting this error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'HomeHomeController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/ng/areq?p0=HomeHomeController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at http://127.0.0.1:17315/Scripts/angular.js:80:12
    at assertArg (http://127.0.0.1:17315/Scripts/angular.js:1610:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://127.0.0.1:17315/Scripts/angular.js:1620:3)
    at http://127.0.0.1:17315/Scripts/angular.js:8319:9
    at http://127.0.0.1:17315/Scripts/angular.js:7496:34
    at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:17315/Scripts/angular.js:343:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:17315/Scripts/angular.js:7483:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:17315/Scripts/angular.js:6991:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:17315/Scripts/angular.js:6870:30)
    at compile (http://127.0.0.1:17315/Scripts/angular-ui-router.js:3335:9)
```

Here is the way I am doing the router config:

```
app.config([
    '$httpProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    '$sceProvider',
    '$stateProvider',
    appConfig
]);

function appConfig(
    $httpProvider,
    $locationProvider,
    $sceProvider,
    $stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider
    ) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    ..
     var home = {
        name: 'home',
        url: '/Home',
        views: {
            'root': {
                templateUrl: '/Content/app/home/partials/home.html',
            },
            'content': {
                templateUrl: '/Content/app/home/partials/overview.html',
            },
        }
    };
    ..
    $stateProvider
        ..
        .state(home)
        ;
```

Here is the order of my script loads:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
...
<script src="/Content/app/home/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/home/home.js"></script>

<script src="/Content/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/appConfig.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/appRun.js"></script>
```

Can anyone tell me if there is aproblem with the way that I am defining my controller using Typescript?

Comment: Try to add export before class definition

Comment: Would that be something new that came about with 1.3? I just tried going back to v1.3.0-beta.8 and my application is working. Went to 1.3 and it gives this error again.

Comment: Totally random guess based on the call stack -- is the router config function running before the class declaration executes?

Comment: Hi Ryan, It's not random. v1.3.0-beta.8 works all the time. v1.3 works none of the type. I updated the question to show how I do the ui-router config. Let me know if you have any other questions and I can update my question to make it more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite of the fact, that you describe that only change is angular JS upgrade, I would like to give you a hint, how this error could be reproduced. I followed your description above and created [this **broken** plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k73EfC5CzsDcDwR82rUH?p=preview) with this state definition:

```
var home = {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/Home',
    views: {
        'root': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl.home.html',
            controller: 'HomeHomeController',
        },
        'content': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl.overview.html',
            controller: 'homeContentController',
        }
    }
};
```

And because the angular's controller definition (following the question) is:

```
var app = angular.module('home', ['ui.router', 'services'])
    .controller('homeHomeController', HomeHomeController)
    .controller('homeContentController', HomeContentController);
```

this gets the error:

```
 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'HomeHomeController' is not a function, got undefined  
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/ng/areq?p0=HomeHomeController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
...
```

So, what is wrong? **`controller: 'HomeHomeController',`**

```
views: {
    'root': {
        templateUrl: 'tpl.home.html',
        controller: 'HomeHomeController',
```

If we fix it to **`controller: 'homeHomeController'`** (camel case name), everything is working

Here is [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/y9ezgiTaV565j5eGu45I?p=preview) with working version

```
var home = {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/Home',
    views: {
        'root': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl.home.html',
            controller: 'homeHomeController',
        },
        'content': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl.overview.html',
            controller: 'homeContentController',
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I checked my .html files and I was referencing the controllers like this: ng-controller="HomeHomeController as home".  This worked pre 1.3 but for 1.3 I have to change to ng-controller="homeHomeController as home".  I am wondering why it ever worked pre-1.3 but the good thing is I now see the mistake and all is working okay. I will accept your answer.

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow... ;)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to tell from your question, but the most likely reason for this error is ordering.

Perhaps when you upgraded the version of Angular, you moved a script tag or the new version of Angular has a subtly different execution time (i.e. it used to wait for `onload` and now it doesn't).

Make sure your controller is declared before you call `angular.module('home', [])...`.

If the two code blocks you included are in different files, make sure the file containing `HomeHomeController` is included before the the file that has the call to `angular.module('home', [])...`

Comment: The new version of Angular simply replaced the old so no ordering difference there in the index.html. My controller is loaded before the angular.module('home' also.  I think it must be something else as this code has worked with many versions of Angular up to now. Right now it's very repeatable. Soon as I go to the latest AngularJS it gives the problem. WHen I go back to the beta it works fine. Do you have any ideas as to how I might be able to get more information on this failure. Often AngularJS error messages give me an idea but not quite enough info to easily track the problem.